# Data extraction by beautifulsoup and re

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I'm tring to extract spcify information from jb hifi, here is what I did:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import re



url="http://www.jbhifionline.com.au/support.aspx?post=1&results=10&source=all&bnSearch=Go!&q=ipod&submit=Go"

page=urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())
Item0=soup.findAll('td',{'class':'check_title'})[0]    
print (Item0.renderContents())
```

the output is :

```
Apple iPod Classic 160GB (Black)Â 
<span class="SKU">MC297ZP/A</span>
```

what I want is:

```
Apple iPod Classic 160GB (Black)
```

and I tried use re to remove the other information

```
 print(Item0.renderContents()).replace{^<span:,""}
```

but it didn't work

So my problem is how can I remove the useless information and get "Apple ipod classic 160GB(black)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `.renderContents()`; it's a debugging tool at best.

Just get the first child:

```
>>> Item0.contents[0]
u'Apple iPod Classic 160GB (Black)\xc2\xa0\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'
>>> Item0.contents[0].strip()
u'Apple iPod Classic 160GB (Black)\xc2'
```

It appears that BeautifulSoup hasn't quite guessed the encoding correctly, so the non-breaking space (U+00a0) is present as two separate bytes instead of one. It looks like BeautifulSoup guessed wrong:

```
>>> soup.originalEncoding
'iso-8859-1'
```

You can force the encoding by using the response headers; this server did set the character set:

```
>>> page.info().getparam('charset')
'utf-8'
>>> page=urllib2.urlopen(url)
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read(), fromEncoding=page.info().getparam('charset'))
>>> Item0=soup.findAll('td',{'class':'check_title'})[0]
>>> Item0.contents[0].strip()
u'Apple iPod Classic 160GB (Black)'
```

The `fromEncoding` parameter tells BeautifulSoup to use UTF-8 instead of Latin 1, and now the non-breaking space is correctly stripped.